# JSON datafile with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

Need your help, trying to change this script:
https://github.com/MrHus/jquery-monthly-ical

To load external JSON data files. So not local in the javascript or with a PHP array with JSON but a real .json data file.

This is the current script:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {   
        $("#ical").ical({
            /*beforeMonth:function(date)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "action.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: "date="+date,
                    async: false,
                    success: function(json){
                        $.fn.ical.changeEventDates(json); 
                    }   
                })
            },*/
            //daynames: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
            //startOnSunday: true,


              eventdates: [{"date": "2009-03-21", "title": "My birthday", "desc": "Its my birthday!"},
                         {"date": "yyyy-01-01", "title": "New Year", "desc": "Its a new year!"},
                         {"date": "2009-mm-01", "title": "New Month", "desc": "First day of the new month!"},
                         {"date": "2010-mm-01", "title": "New Month", "desc": "First day of the new month!"},
                         {"date": "2010-09-01", "title": "Convention", "desc": "September convention."}, 
                         {"date": "2010-09-02", "title": "Convention", "desc": "September convention day two."}, 
                         {"date": "2010-mm-01", "title": "Towl", "desc": "Dont forget to bring a towl."}    
                        ]
        });
    });
```

How can I use a .json file with the same data as: But the eventdates: line must be before it in the JavaScript because I dont have this in my JSON files.

```
    eventdates: [{"date": "2009-03-21", "title": "My birthday", "desc": "Its my birthday!"},
                         {"date": "yyyy-01-01", "title": "New Year", "desc": "Its a new year!"},
                         {"date": "2009-mm-01", "title": "New Month", "desc": "First day of the new month!"},
                         {"date": "2010-mm-01", "title": "New Month", "desc": "First day of the new month!"},
                         {"date": "2010-09-01", "title": "Convention", "desc": "September convention."}, 
                         {"date": "2010-09-02", "title": "Convention", "desc": "September convention day two."}, 
                         {"date": "2010-mm-01", "title": "Towl", "desc": "Dont forget to bring a towl."}    
                           ]
```

Currently no succes showing my JSON data from the file. This is the part of the JavaScript that handles the JSON. But not working, please help.

```
            var month = getMonthNumber($("#currentmonth", obj).text());
            var year = $("#currentyear", obj).text();

            var formatdate = formatDate(year, month, i);

            var jsondates  = getEventDates(formatdate)

            if (jsondates.length === 0)
            {
                options.beforeDay(formatdate);
                $(".icaltable tr:last", obj).append("<td id = '"+formatdate+"'>"+i+"</td"); //add day
            }
            else
            {
                var firstEvent = true;
                for (var k = 0; k < jsondates.length; k++)
                {
                    var datejson = jsondates[k];
                    options.beforeDay(formatdate);

                    //alert(datejson.title);

                    var str = "<li><span class='title'>"+ datejson.LOCATION +"</span><span class='desc'>"+ datejson.SUMMARY +"</span></li>"

                    if (firstEvent)
                    {
                        $(".icaltable tr:last", obj).append("<td class='date_has_event' id = '"+ formatdate +"'>"+i+"<div class='events'><ul id ='ul-"+ formatdate +"'>"+ str +"</ul></div></td>"); //add day  
                        firstEvent = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#ul-" + formatdate, obj).append(str);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        if (options.startOnSunday){
            startOnSunday = 1;
        } 

        for (var i = 0; i < afterpadding - startOnSunday; i++) //add after padding
        {
            $(".icaltable tr:last", obj).append("<td class = 'padding'></td");
        }

        highlightToday(obj);
    };

    function getMonthNumber(month){
        for (var i = 0; i < options.monthnames.length; i++)
        {
            if (options.monthnames[i] === month)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
    };

    function getDaysInMonth(year, month){
        return 32 - new Date(year, month, 32).getDate();
    };

    function highlightToday(obj){
        var today = new Date();
        today = formatDate(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate());
        $("#"+today, obj).addClass("today");
    };

    function getEventDates(date){

        var results = [];

        for (var i = 0;  i < eventdates.length; i++)
        {     
            var evaldate = evaluateEventDate(eventdates[i]["DTSTART"], date);
            if (date === evaldate)
            {
                results.push(eventdates[i]);
            } 
        }

        return results;
    };

    function evaluateEventDate(eventdate, date){
        var eventdate = eventdate.split('-');
        var date = date.split('-');

        if (eventdate[0] === 'yyyy')
        {
            eventdate[0] = date[0];
        }

        if (eventdate[1] === 'mm') 
        {
            eventdate[1] = date[1];
        }

        if (eventdate[2] === 'dd')
        {
            eventdate[2] = date[2];
        }

        return eventdate[0]+'-'+eventdate[1]+'-'+eventdate[2];
    };

    function getLastDayOfMonth(year, month, days){
        var date = new Date(year, month, days);
        if (date.getDay() == 0)//we start on monday!
        {
            return 6;
        }
        else
        {
            return date.getDay() -1;
        }
    };
```

This is the json data example:

```
            [
  {
    "DTSTAMP": "20010101T000000Z", 
    "DESCRIPTION": "Hartel-Kuwait", 
    "TRANSP": "TRANSPARENT", 
    "SUMMARY": "HW ", 
    "LOCATION": "Hartel", 
    "DTEND": "20110816", 
    "DTSTART": "20110815", 
    "CATEGORIES": "Tide20110815HARTKWT", 
    "UID": "0.625169509629817"
  }
            ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are close with your commented out code.

It says that before every month is loaded it will use AJAX to get the event dates from the source you specify.

In the example, it tries to get events from the `action.php` script. However, if you want to use a hardcoded .json file for every month, you can simply replace `action.php` with `test.json`.

Your new code could be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {   
        $("#ical").ical({
            beforeMonth:function(date)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "test.json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function(json){
                        $.fn.ical.changeEventDates(json); 
                    }   
                })
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I haven't actually used this particular library, but have used ones with a very similar syntax.

Comment: Ok im a little bit futher, but have edited my question. Because its still not working.

Comment: Do you know the exact error the Javascript is giving (perhaps by using the console)? After a quick glance, it looks as though maybe your dates in `DTSTART` and `DTEND` aren't quite in the right format?

Comment: No can't get it to work. No errors, just no data in the calender,

Comment: The `evaluateEventDate` function is expecting `DTSTART` to be in the format yyyy-mm-dd (`eventdate.split('-')`), so your current JSON probably wont give any results. If it still doesn't work and its failing silently it could possibly be a JSON format error or typo.

Comment: evaluateEventDate deleted as a function. But still an empty calender.

Comment: You deleted the function? I didn't mean that, you need that function. Just try changing your `DTSTART` and `DTEND` from `20110815` and `20110816 ` to `2011-08-15` and `2011-08-16 `.

Comment: Adam this is my new post. I have eliminated all problems except the date split: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977688/format-yyymmdd-date