# Format yyymmdd date

Tags: javascript, date, slice

I need this javascript function to not split a yyyy-mm-dd but split a yyymmdd.
Current date formats are 2011-11-02 but this function needs to work with 20111102.

Script:

```
        function evaluateEventDate(eventdate, date){
        var eventdate = eventdate.split('-');
        var date = date.split('-');

        if (eventdate[0] === 'yyyy')
        {
            eventdate[0] = date[0];
        }

        if (eventdate[1] === 'mm') 
        {
            eventdate[1] = date[1];
        }

        if (eventdate[2] === 'dd')
        {
            eventdate[2] = date[2];
        }

        return eventdate[0]+'-'+eventdate[1]+'-'+eventdate[2];
    };
```

Comment: This seems to be `javascript` and not `json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing my work from your other question, I came up with the following function to solve your problem, using `substr`:

```
function evaluateEventDate(eventdate, date){
    var event_y = eventdate.substr(0, 4);
    var event_m = eventdate.substr(4, 2);
    var event_d = eventdate.substr(6, 2);

    var date = date.split('-');

    if (event_y === 'yyyy')
    {
        event_y = date[0];
    }

    if (event_m === 'mm') 
    {
        event_m = date[1];
    }

    if (event_d === 'dd')
    {
        event_d = date[2];
    }

    return event_y + '-' + event_m + '-' + event_d;
};
```

Comment: If it helped you, I would appreciate you marking it as an answer :)

Answer (score 5):

You could do this:

```
var date = date.match(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/); // [yyyymmdd, yyyy, mm, dd]
date.shift(); // remove yyyymmdd from array.
...
```

Comment: This is a much nicer way of doing it, if you just changed `date` to `eventdate` so he can slot it right into his code.